# Generate consecutive page numbers + ToC from 28 .tex files?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, covers

I've completed half a semester of Discrete Mathematics.

I have written up all 28 lectures into individual .tex files, labelled Lecture1.tex Lecture 2.tex ... Lecture28.tex.

The beginning of each one (give or take a few packages) is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}

\title{Discrete Mathematics -- Lecture 28}
\author{Alec Taylor}
\date{September 16, 2011}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
```

How can I automatically generate a single PDF with the contents of all 28 .tex files with:

- Consecutive numbering of all pages
- Table of Contents
- Cover page

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! You can highlight your syntax by indenting it with 4 spaces as I have done. Also, you don't need to sign your questions since they are signed automatically.

Comment: I've downloaded the zip file with the .tex files. There are a few problems that you may want to address and then re-upload the files in question: (1) lecture5.tex is missing; (2) files lecture1.tex through lecture9.tex use the (grossly obsolete!) latex209 `\documentstyle`  declaration instead of latex2e's `\documentclass`; (3) duplicate files: lecture2/3, lecture 27/28; (4) lecture4 does not compile, crashes with a `Runaway argument?` message. You should probably address these issues before you ask others for advice on how to stitch together the separate files.

Comment: When you say that your code is "up on MediaFire", I assume that the place to look for is stated in your most recent comment to my previously-posted answer, i.e., http://mediafire.com/?qhpem71z3m3mpzq. If this assumption is not correct, please post the appropriate URL. Thanks.

Comment: I've been learning TeX as I go, so bound to make some mistakes on the way. I've added a bounty, so if you can get the PDF to compile properly, I'll give you the bounty :]. Feel free to edit any of the .tex files to do this (without commenting/deleting out the actual content!).

Comment: since a couple of people have reported that their solutions work when they try them with your files, i would suspect package version conflicts.  if you include your .log file in your test bundle, that would allow this possibility to be checked.

Comment: Related question: [Constructing Conference Proceedings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124942/9075).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`combine`](http://ctan.org/pkg/combine) class to merge the individual lectures into one single document. The "master" file would look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{combine}

\usepackage[nomauthor]{combinet}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}

\title{Discrete Mathematics}
\author{Alec Taylor}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\begin{papers}
    \import{Lecture1}
    \import{Lecture2}
    % ...
    \import{Lecture28}
\end{papers}
\end{document}
```

The individual lectures are included with the [`\import`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf#page=6) command. Please note that you have to load all the packages you have used in your lectures in your main document. (As an alternative, you could use the [`packages`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf#page=4) class option which does this automatically, but this is somewhat experimental.)

In order to include all the lectures into the table of contents, I have added [`\usepackage{combinet}`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf#page=11) in the above example - this is an additional package which takes care of it automatically. The [`nomauthor`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf#page=11) option suppresses adding the author to the table of contents (as it is alway "Alec Taylor", as far as I have understood you).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this didn't work. My .tex file: http://pastebin.tlhiv.org/yPwYU_Pv The error: ! LaTeX Error: Command \xP@lw already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

Comment: `\xP@lw` seems to be an internal macro used by the [`xypic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xypic) package. It is used at the beginning of the document (with `\AtBeginDocument`) - but as they are multiple `\begin{document}` now, this confuses the package. The [`combine` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf#page=11) suggests putting `\emptyAtBeginDocument` directly after the `\begin{document}` of your *main file* when such problems occur, which works fine in my minimal test case.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that didn't make a difference. :\

Comment: @AT It's difficult for me to reproduce your problem without having the actual `Lecture*.tex` files. Try posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. (I guess it doesn't need 28 lectures for the error to show up - try creating the smallest configuration where the problem still exists.)

Comment: Test-case: http://pastebin.tlhiv.org/Pf3LviMo

Comment: @AT Your test case works fine for me if I add `\emptyAtBeginDocument` to the main document like this: [http://pastebin.tlhiv.org/CEq28gn6](http://pastebin.tlhiv.org/CEq28gn6)

Comment: diabonas: I keep getting other errors, from heaps of my files, it's probably an easy fix. Can you take a look at my .tex files? - http://www.mediafire.com/?qhpem71z3m3mpzq

Comment: @AT I've set up a main file which should (hopefully `:-)`) compile correctly: http://www.mediafire.com/?iz1cneepddqq86c It doesn't include all your lectures, though: The lectures 4,6,8,10,17 have LaTeX errors which need to be fixed first - try compiling the single files first to see what's wrong with them. Lectures 15 and 16 are valid LaTeX code, but they use `ntheorem`, a package which is apparently incompatible with the `combine` class. BTW: Some of your lectures use `\documentstyle` instead of `\documentclass` - this is a deprecated LaTeX 2.09 command which should be avoided.

Comment: Lecture 10 compiles fine, I've fixed lectures 6 & 8, but lecture 17... I need a double subscript... also, unsure how fix lecture 4.

Comment: @AT *Lecture 10:* You're right, it is fine, I just didn't have the included picture, so it produced an error message. *Lecture 17:* Enclose the double subscript into braces: `$P_{g_-}$` instead of `$P_g_-$` should work fine. *Lecture 4:* You mixed up curly and round braces: It's `\Vertex{A}` (l. 25) and `\EA(A){C}` instead of `\EA{A}(C)` etc. (l. 26-34) I uploaded the corrected file here: http://www.mediafire.com/?j4tin2kz6c552l3

Comment: Thanks, almost done. Everything compiled (fixed remainder, even remove dependency for ntheorem from Lectures 15-16). Unfortunately the ToC page is empty. I'm running the latest TeXlive on Windows 8 x64... how can I populate the ToC page?

Comment: @AT It works for me (using the version http://www.mediafire.com/?iz1cneepddqq86c). I can think of two possibilities: Either you've compiled the main file only once (you need to run `pdflatex` at least twice to generate the necessary auxiliary files for the TOC), or you haven't loaded the `combinet` package in your main document (which takes care of the automatic table of contents).

Comment: Ah, I only compiled it once. Thanks, all works now.

Comment: Strange though, Lecture 12 shows weird symbols (bet, some greek symbols &etc) only when collated to the one document. On it's own, it presents fine. Any ideas?

Comment: @AT Thank you for the bounty `:-)` The "weird symbol error" you encountered is a truly strange one - it seems as if the math alphabet isn't switched back from the blackboard bold to the default one... I can't explain this strange behaviour at all, nor why it occurs only in the combined document. At least, I can provide a workaround: Enclose the `\mathbb{}` macros in `Lecture12.tex` into curly braces (e.g. `{\mathbb{N}}`) - this produces the correct characters in my test case.

Comment: Wow, that sucked. Had to manually replaced run f&r on all my documents to enclose all the \mathbb{letter} and \mathcal{letter} in braces :\. Thanks though for finding the problem, enjoy the bounty!

Answer (score 3):

Given the nature of the document you're trying to create -- a single set of lecture notes -- I wonder if you'd be better off *not* more or less simply combining the existing files (which, from your description, are standalone TeX files with `\title`, `\author`, etc information) but, instead, took the time to (re)organize them a bit more flexibly, along the following lines.

1. Take each individual lecture file -- for concreteness, suppose you're working on `lecture1.tex` -- and cut out everything between (but not including) the `\maketitle` and `\end{document}` commands. Paste the cut-out code into a new file named `lecture1-body.tex`, and insert the instruction `\input lecture1-body` in the "main" file (`lecture1.tex`). Repeat 28 times. This way, you'll preserve all of your "old" files, should the need to print them out as separate standalone files arise.
2. Create a new LaTeX style file named, say, `discmath.sty`. In this file, you should load the various LaTeX packages you've already been loading as well as all macros and shortcuts you've created so far for the individual lectures. Go through the preambles of your 28 "main" files and scan them for `\usepackage`, `\newcommand`, and `\renewcommand` (and similar) instructions, and then copy-and-paste them into the new "style" file, omitting duplicates as needed. If you've been slipping in the habit of creating new macros "on the fly" inside the main bodies of the lecture files (not encouraged, obviously, but not impossible either), now's the time to move them into the main style file.
3. Create a new driver file, say `discmath-lectures.tex`. Given the nature of the document you're trying to create, the `book` or `report` document classes would seem more appropriate than the `article` class for this new driver file. In this file, you'll first load your new style file, create a new overall title as well as a table of contents, and then (in the body of the file) load each of the 28 `...-body.tex` files in turn.

This file would look something likeX

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{discmath}
\title{Lecture Notes\\Discrete Mathematics}
\author{Alex Taylor}
\date{\nodate} % use \nodate if you don't want to show a date at all
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction to Discrete Mathematics (or some other title)}
\include lecture1-body
\chapter{Xyz}
\include lecture2-body
...
\chapter{Additional thoughts}
\include lecture28-body
\begin{bibliography}{99}
... [to be created by you]
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

An issue you don't raise in your answer is whether or not each lecture is a self-contained unit (or "chapter", for the purposes of this document). The MWE above assumes that this is the case. If that's not the case, however, you should of course adjust the `\chapter` commands appropriately. Happy TeXing!

**Addendum** after the OP posted the log file of his program. I noticed the following lines toward the very end, just before "Here is how much of TeX's memory you used":

```
Chapter 3.
[7]
\openout2 = `l.aux'.

No file l.tex
```

This message strongly suggests that LaTeX is being instructed to open a file named `l.tex`, which doesn't exist. Is there a typo in your .tex file, possibly in the area where lecture3-body.tex should be loaded?

Comment: Automated individual document processing: http://codepad.org/izUMRp01

Comment: Unfortunately I only get 10 pages (with just what you have above minus '...'), with no content from my other .tex files. How can I make this work?

Comment: If you get 10 pages, does this mean you're getting a title page and then lectures 1 through 9 only? If so, could you check your code for a "feature" that doesn't allow for the possibility of 2-digit numbers? By the way, what does the `.log` file have to say on this -- does LaTex actually try to load files 10 through 28 according to the log file?

Comment: Here's the logfile: http://pastebin.com/jt3F1emb - I don't get any content from my lectures (which are all 2 or more pages), just get the chapter section titles from the first tex.

Comment: Thanks for posting the .log file. See the addendum to my answer for comments.

Comment: "\openout2 = `l.aux'" would come from a line like the above "\include lecture1-body" -- \include needs braces

Comment: Thanks Mico, but unfortunately it still isn't working for me. Please test it with my original .tex files: http://mediafire.com/?qhpem71z3m3mpzq