# Merging many tex-documents together?

Tags: document-configuration

I have a serie of publication papers that I would like to gather into one group of papers (or a collection). Is there some easy way for that without removing all headers such as `\documentclass{article}...etc`? I initially thought about just appending them as PDFs but it is a bit poor looking -- page numbers not getting fixed or anything like that.

1. How would you merge such papers?
2. Is it possible to autogenerate finding-aid for such documents? (It is extremely hard reading without some instructions about the papers.)

Comment: Have a look at the `standalone` package.

Comment: I don't understand the second request. However, a solution to the first is probable available from: [Make a `.tex` file that combines complete `.tex` documents in subdirectories](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21997/5764). As such, I think this is a dupe (if we consider only single-question posts).

Comment: ...takes me some time to check the standalone...then I can comment more about dupenesss.

Comment: @hhh Also have a look at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/confproc

Comment: ...anyone with working MWO for standalone? (I messes up now with something, getting just one page standalone document...)

Comment: Try adding the class options `crop=false,preview=false` to `standalone`. If that does not work, please compose a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem you are having.

Comment: You could use the [`combine`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/combine) class: It is designed for merging different papers into one document and generating a commmon table of contents etc. An example on how to use it can be found in the question [Generate consecutive page numbers + ToC from 28 .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28727/3323)

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new document as a frame. Just a class, pdfpages and maybe babel.
2. For each paper add a section or a chapter, depending on the class of your frame.
3. Add a \tableofcontents
4. Include your papers by using the pdfpages package.
5. But add them piece by piece and adapt the pagenumber in each of the papers. I can't tell you exactly how to do that, usually you should do something like \setcounter{\page}{newpagenumber}, let the paper compile and then compile the frame. Open the frame document and have a look at the last page. Take this number, add 1, open the next paper, adapt the pagenumber, compile it, include it into the frame, compile the frame and so on.

You will get your table of contents with a list of all papers and their respective page.

pdfpages allows to add a headline to each pdf.