# Merging several papers

Tags: document-configuration

[This link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45558/merging-many-tex-documents-together) seems to have the answer.

But what does he mean by "Create a new document as a frame"?

Also whatever it is how do you create it in TeXnicCenter?

Baz

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{TransferPanel.pdf}



 \includepdf[pages=-]{rv-Nss.pdf}
 \end{document}
```

This was my attempt to follow the instructions.

The resulting PDF does contain the two papers in their entirety, this is 90% what I want, all that remains is that I would like the page numbers to be consecutive?

I guess this means I have to:

1. Remove the page numbers from the orginal papers
2. Then add page numbers to this new document?

It's the second part that I'm not sure of?

Comment: Create a new document only with `\documentclass{report}` and that packages suggested there. Then you insert the papers using `pdfpages` tools.

Comment: You haven't provided much detail about your requirements. You might take a look at the `combine` package: http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf

Comment: Hi I'd still like to be able to edit the page numbers to that they are contiguous (except perhaps for appendices/bibliography's). Also I would like to be able to add a table of contents. Will it be possible to add anything more details than chapter1 and Chapter 2? Ideally I would like to give a breakdown of each chapter?

Comment: Is there any reason you need to include them as PDFs. Why not include their source if they are `.tex` files? Then you can easily generate the kinds of information you want to include. (You can get the pages anyway - see the documentation for pdfpages on how to do this.)

Comment: I suggest you to use `\pagestyle{empty}` in `TransferPanel.tex` and `rv-Nss.tex` and then `\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\pagestyle{plain}}]{TransferPanel.pdf}` and `\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\pagestyle{plain}}]{rv-Nss.pdf}`

Comment: What about `\pageref`-references within the single pdf-files  which you wish to merge? What about the table(s) of contents?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a simple question as it could be. The hard part are the hyperlinks and the page numbers.

### Aims of my solution

I had to generate proceedings for [LNI](https://gi.de/service/publikationen/lni/) and had following aims:

- Automatic generation of

  - running heads (including page numbers, authors, title of the paper)
  - table of contents
  - PDF bookmarks
  - index
  - `proceedings.bib` listing all papers including page numbers
- Working hyperlinks

  - from the TOC to the papers
  - within the papers
  - from the index to the papers

### The solution

I came up with my own solution heavily relying on

- [koma-script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) for the layout (TOC, separating pages, ...),
- [pdfpages](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) to include the papers,
- [pax](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pax) to enable hyperlinks
- [biblatex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and [xindy](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xindy) to generate the index

The solution is more than 400 lines of LaTeX, which come with other scripts. 
The complete result is available at https://gi-ev.github.io/LNI-proceedings/.

### Considered alternatives

When designing this solution to typeset complete proceedings, several alternatives were investigated.
Nearly all possible alternatives are listed at http://www.ctan.org/topic/confproc.
In the following, evaluated alternatives are listed and discussed.

#### confproc

[confproc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/confproc) seems to the most suitable alternative.
Compared with this approach, it has following drawbacks:

- The PDFs of the papers do not take a proper heading (page numbers, editor).
- When clicking on a link in one included PDF, the linked PDF is opened instead of jumping to the link.
- Indexing of authors has to be done by manually.

#### combine

The [combine](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/combine) class combines the sources of different LaTeX together.
Since there might be conflicting packages, we wanted to include each PDF on its own.
It seems to be more easy to typeset each paper for itself (LaTeX, Word) and then to combine the resulting PDFs.

#### proc

[proc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/proc) is a very basic class based on the article class.
No update since 1995.