# How to merge several tex files so that they have one table of contents/List of tables & figures

Tags: table-of-contents, input, include, thesis, document-configuration

I have three chapters which I combine into a thesis using pdfpages: as shown in this link

[Merging several papers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160507/merging-several-papers)

This gets me 95% of what I need the only thing I still need is a table of contents including all sub-sections for each chapter, and similarly a table listing all the tables and figures across all three chapters.

What is the simplest way to so this? All three chapters compile individually no problem.

I also tried using:

[When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)

\input and \include

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

but when I tried this it included all the pre-ample from the tex file in the document?

Also some of the equations were displayed larger and hence were off the page! In the file generated using \input, but they appear fine when the tex file is compiled as a stand alone document?

Please note I'm really not good with Latex so the simplest solution please.

Happy to post what ever code you like but the tex files are rather large.

@ Jean

I tired your code it's a step in the right direction. 
There is a table of contents.
However only chapter one appears in the output, both in the TOC and as a file, Chapter Two does not appear anywhere. 
And all the \usepackage preamble is printed in the document between the contents and the beginning of chapter 1

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} \tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter One} \input{Introduction.tex}
\chapter{Chapter Two} \input{rv-NSS.tex}
\end{document} `
```

[image: Table of Contents with overlapping entry on first line]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{code}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{example}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
\usepackage[%
 font=small,
 labelfont=bf,
 figurewithin=section,
 tablewithin=section,
 tableposition=top
]{caption}
 \numberwithin{equation}{section}

\makeatletter
\def\env@matrix{\hskip -\arraycolsep
 \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
 \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols l}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\input{title.tex}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\chapter\addtocontents{toc}{Chapter One}\input{Introduction.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{My Chapter}`?

Comment: the simplest way is to make a single document and _not_ have `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` in each chapter, and just `\input` or `\include` each chapter into the main document

Comment: So the only way to do it is by manually putting in each section sub section and subsection from each chapter?

Comment: @David so for each tex file that I had previously been using to create the pdf's I should cut and paste then into a new tex file (one each) that doesn't have \documentclass or \begin document? I assume that I should remove the \usepackages from these new tex files as well? But how then will the final document look correct?

Comment: It's possible to combine separate pdf files, but really I'd only do that for things like conference proceedings joining articles by different authors. For a single document like a thesis it is _much_ easier to automate numbering and cross references between sections in different chapters if it is a single document.

Comment: A thesis should use consistent formatting and layout. So you want a single preamble to ensure that the layout of all parts of your thesis are rendered correctly. Otherwise, any change you make to one part's preamble has to be manually copied to all the others.

Comment: http://ctan.org/pkg/docmute may be of interest. It allows you to input/include the contents of other files ignoring their preambles entirely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method of compiling only one "main" document does not work for you?

Like the mainTexFile.tex...that should have the `\begin{document}` argument etc....the rest would be simple tex files with sections, chapters, etc...

Like this...

Code for a "Main" tex file.

```
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\input{\...path_to_a_file...\chapterOne.tex}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\input{\...path_to_a_file...\chapterTwo.tex}

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\input{\...path_to_a_file...\chapterThree.tex}

\end{document}
```

This should be working...It worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Hi Jean please see edit added above.

Comment: OK I removed the \begin{document}/ \end{document} from the tex files and now both chapters are included. However it's still printing the preamble from each tex file. I guess I need to remove those too? And add them to the main file?

Comment: Of course :) ..... remember "One Main File". I usually name the main file the...title of my article, book, whatever. Any style any package....everything must be...before \begin{document}! Simple...

Comment: Thanks!!! Each tex file has a lot of images that should also be included. What do I have to do to get those to display as well? Note that I copied the tex files for the first two chapters to the local directory. However if I reference the original tex using the paths as shown above will \input automatically pick up the image files? Or do I still need to do something extra?

Comment: Also each chapter should have it's own bilbiography and appendices can I have multiple bibliographies and appendices with this solution?

Comment: \includegraphics or whatever should be addressed in regard always to the Main.tex directory. If that is what you are asking...
Like 
Folder_main(working dir)->/chapters
                        ->/images
                        ->/whatever
           

Something like this can be used also to minimise paths...but it's not a necessity. 
'\newcommand{\CHAPTERDIR}{\WORKDIR chapters/}'

Comment: Regarding bibliography...i haven't used it...but let's say that if you find a way just to add...into the main's.tex bibliography each chapter's citations. Then by the end of the \input{chapters..} you will end up with a full bibliography table. 
But I haven't done it...so don't take that for granted. Just find if there is a way...adding form each chapter.tex into a bibltex file. Then finaly showing it! :)

Comment: The \chapter{Chapter One} just appears as text on the document and is not included in the table of contents? Also I would like it so that the sections start counting from 1 for each new chapter I assume this will work when we get the \chapter{Chapter One} command working

Comment: `\chapter{Chapter One}` did not appear in TOC? Try forcing it...by 

`\addtocontents{toc}{desired Name}` right after the `\chapter`. 

It should be working without it though...

Comment: Tried that it shows "Chapter One" but it then shown "Abstract" which is the next section header on top of it?

Comment: Give me when you can...a sample of your main.tex
Not full....cause I can't reproduce it...I'll missing the rest of the .tex. Or a picture...to visualise a little the situation.

Comment: OK I gave you full main because not sure what not to include plus a picture of the contents where chapter one and abstract overlap

Comment: `\chapter\addtocontents{toc}{Chapter One}\input{Introduction.tex}`

This line is faulty I think...
It should either be 
`\chapter{Chapter One}`
`\addtocontents{toc}{Chapter One}` %not necessary 
`\input{Intro.tex}`

Or have in Intro.tex the `\chapter{Chapter's name}` ...and nothing else in the main.tex...

Comment: I tried \chapter{Chapter One} on one  line followed by \input{Intro.tex} on the next. In this case chapter one does not appear in the contents at all and chapter one appears as regular text just before abstract in the document.

Comment: I then tried \addtocontents{toc}{Chapter One} followed by \input{Intro.tex} on the next line. This has the same overlapping chapter one and abstract on the contents page as shown in the picture above. There is no Chapter One shown in the document.

Comment: Doing the same intro.tex did not seem to make any difference. It's like latex doesn't understand the chapter command. Maybe I should open this as a new question?

Comment: Note that if I use \part{Chapter 1} it works and gives me what I want apart from the fact that Part I appears before {Chapter One} in the text. If I could make the Part I not appear in the text while keeping the Chapter 1 in the table of contents would be problem solved. Would still like to know why chapter is not working though

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example using [docmute](http://ctan.org/pkg/docmute). This avoids the need to delete the preamble from the included files which means they can still be compiled independently when appropriate. Essentially the `docmute` package causes the preambles of files which are included or input into the main file to be entirely ignored.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}% only so I can include the 'separate' chapters here for convenience (LaTeX writes new files with the given names on compilation which are then \input below)
\begin{filecontents}{ch1.tex}
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
    \kant[1-4]
  \end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ch2.tex}
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
    \kant[5-9]
  \end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}% only to provide filler text for the example
\usepackage{docmute}
\title{Thesis}
\author{You}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\input{ch1}% preamble will be ignored
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\input{ch2}% preamble will be ignored
\end{document}
```

[image: combining files without their preambles]

## Update

[appendix](http://ctan.org/pkg/appendix) can be used to add appendices to each chapter. For example, this adds one appendix to the first chapter and two to the second:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ch1.tex}
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
    \kant[1-4]
    \begin{subappendices}
      \section{Appendix for First Chapter}
        \kant[10]
    \end{subappendices}
  \end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ch2.tex}
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
    \kant[5-9]
    \begin{subappendices}
      \section{First Appendix for Second Chapter}
        \kant[11]
      \section{Second Appendix for Second Chapter}
        \kant[12]
    \end{subappendices}
  \end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{docmute,appendix}
\title{Thesis}
\author{You}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\input{ch1}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\input{ch2}
\end{document}
```

[image: appendix for first chapter]

See the package documentation for details of the ways in which this may be customised.

Comment: Thanks but I have the same question as above each chapter should have it's own appendices and bibliography can this be achieved with this solution?

Comment: @Bazman Definitely you can have separate bibliographies. If you are using `biblatex`, this is provided by the package. If you are using `bibtex`, you need an additional package such as `bibunits`. Either way, it is definitely possible. I'm not sure about appendices but I imagine this could be managed. Are these formatted as a section? A separate chapter? It depends a bit on how you have configured things.

Comment: @Bazman http://ctan.org/pkg/appendix should be helpful for the appendices. As I say, the bibliographies depends on how you are managing them.

Comment: @Bazman See my edited answer for an example using per-chapter appendices. For the bibliographies, you'd need to provide details of the tools you are using to manage references.

Comment: really helpful to hear about `docmute` - many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Besides using the packages linked by @cfr, I think this may be achieved properly separating preambles and content into different files. If you write the preamble of a work, and maybe the titlepage and TOC, in `work1_main.tex` and the content in `work1_content.tex` you may compile just it alone or include the content in a bigger document.

Say we have n independent works and we want to compile them separately and together. It is sensible to place the files in a folder with a structure similar to:

```
-main.tex
+work1
--work1_main.tex
--work1_content.tex
--bibliography1.bib
+work2
--work2_main.tex
--work2_content.tex
--bibliography2.bib
+workn
--workn_main.tex
--workn_content.tex
--bibliographyn.bib
```

The content would be:

main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

%all the packages required for the large document (all the works)
%load bibliography1.bib, bibliography2.bib and bibliography3.bib

\begin{document}

%titlepage, tableofcontents...

\chapter{Introduction} %optional
%Introduction text

\chapter{Work 1}
\input{./work1/work1_content.tex}
\chapter{Work 2}
\input{./work2/work2_content.tex}
\chapter{Work n}
\input{./work2/workn_content.tex}

%globalbibliography

\end{document}
```

workn_main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%all the packages required for work n

\begin{document}

%titlepage, tableofcontents...

\input{work1_content.tex}

\end{document}
```

workn_content.tex

```
\section{Introduction to work n}
%Text,figure, tables, subsections, other sections...

%bibliography of work n
```

This way, if you compile `main.tex` you'll get the large document with includes all the works. If you compile `workn_main.tex` you'll get just work n. Although working with more files may seem tedious at first, I think it helps when having to merge or just change format. To make the loading of all the works as chapters easier, you can define a command. For example:

main_easy.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

%all the packages required for the large document (all the works)
%load bibliography1.bib, bibliography2.bib and bibliography3.bib

\newcommand\importchapter[2]{
 \chapter{#1}
 \input{#2}
}

\begin{document}

%titlepage, tableofcontents...

\importchapter{Work 1}{./work1/work1_content.tex}
\importchapter{Work 2}{./work1/work2_content.tex}
\importchapter{Work n}{./work1/workn_content.tex} 

%globalbibliography

\end{document}
```

Since you said you are not goot at LaTeX, I tried to keep the example simple. If you feel like taking this approach we may add how to keep up with `appendices` and the bibliography.

---

In relation to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202075/adding-title-pages-into-document-with-input) this similar question you maid, you could create `workn_main.tex`, `workn_preamble.tex` and `workn_content.tex` for each work. If you try to input all the `work?_preamble` files in the preamble of the main, it will probably crash. You should check those to load each package just once.