# How to input multiple files with specific preambles?

Tags: formatting, preamble

I am finishing my thesis and I need to include all of these minor, standalone project into one pice. However, I have trouble how to bite this problem.

I found many "how-to-input-files" questions but I couldn't get my answer. My case includes 15 files.. and almost all of them have different preamble(few files based on tikz and tikz style settings) which makes me confused.

Could someone give me an advice or simple recipe what should I have to do to make latex read my files ?:)

Comment: Perhaps this is task for the `combine` package?

Comment: Try this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45558/merging-many-tex-documents-together/45622#45622

Comment: There are packages that try to do this, but it's only 15 files and it's your thesis. If it were me I'd take the body of each of the documents without the preamble and input them into a new combined document using a single preamble. That will ensure common style and easier cross referencing. If you have to adjust a few macros in a few of the documents to avoid clashes it's not the end of the world.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thats true but I have a wide range analysis which includes 50 pages of pictures.. To make keep it classy I had to expand my margin, header and footer. I am worried if I paste all of these settings into one I will lose order I worked for. That's main reason posting here.

Comment: geometry package allows you to change the page settings mid docuemnt. But if you don't want there are the combine package approaches which try to import complete documents or simply use pdf tools to concatenate separate pdf files. Hard to say in general, but I'd try to make them one document first.

Comment: Ok I will try it and post the result.